# To create a copy of object in java w/o clone,copy constructor and copy factory

Tags: java

guys although this may sound like a question which is already being asked but its not.

The issue here is simple, i want to create an exact copy of an object without using clone,copy constructor and copy factory methods, because we can't make the changes to the classes(No Rights).
assume i have a Dog object

i want to create one more Dog object and in this duplicate i have to change the values of some attributes but the original object should not get affected in any way

Thanks

Comment: I guess this can be answered only for objects of a specific class.

Comment: Do you have private fields, without getters/setters? In that case, you'll have to use reflection, otherwise it's pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 4):

You can consider serialization/deserialization if the object supports that, but it might be heavy performance-wise.

Using ObjectOutputStream is also another option: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#replaceObject%28java.lang.Object%29

Also look at "Item 76: Write readObject methods defensively" of "Effective Java". It shows some nasty tricks you can play with object input streams.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a new object for `NewDog` using `OldDog`
Have you considered something like this?

```
NewDog dog = new NewDog(someOldDogObject);
```

While constructor of `NewDog` can be.

```
public NewDog(OldDog oldDog){

this.dogWeight = oldDog.dogWeight; // keeping the same weight
this.dogName = "newDog" + oldDog.dogName; // changing your dog name as per rquirement.

}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Using Apache Beanutils

```
Object cloned = BeanUtils.cloneBean(obj);//pass object for cloning
```

2) using reflection

```
 public <T> T clone(T obj1) {
            try {
                Class clazz = obj1.getClass();
                T obj2 = (T) clazz.newInstance();
                Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
                for (Field field : fields) {
                    try {
                        field.setAccessible(true);
                        int modifiers = field.getModifiers();
                        if (!Modifier.isStatic(modifiers) && !Modifier.isFinal(modifiers)) {
                            field.set(obj2, field.get(obj1));
                        }
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                return obj2;
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper class/method:

```
MyObject cloneMyObject(MyObject o) {
    MyObject cloned = new MyObject();
    cloned.fieldOne = o.fieldOne;
    cloned.fieldTwo = o.fieldTwo;
    // Or this depending on how MyObject was implemented
    // cloned.setFieldOne(o.getFieldOne());
    // cloned.setFieldTwo(o.getFieldTwo());
    return cloned;
}
```

As a side note, to get a deep cloned object make sure all the reference types are cloned before they are added to the new object.

Comment: Thanks so much guys will try to implement all of them and will let you all know about it

Answer (score 0):

You can create an util method that will do this for you, just like this

```
public class MyDogUtils {
    public Dog copy(final Dog res, final Dog dest) {
        final Dog ret = (dest == null) ? new Dog() : dest;
        ret.setName(res.getName());
            // some code here
        return ret;
       }
   }
```